# match all strings until specified one occurs in urlrewrite.xml

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I am trying to accomplish a situation where path looking like this one:

> http://verylongpath.com/show.html,a1,b2,c3,stop,d4,e5

would get rewritten to

> path=a1&attributes=b2,c3&splitters=d4,e5
>
> (or more like
>   somepath.html?path=1&attributes=$[numberOfGroup]&splitters=$[numberOfGroup])

so far I have managed to create something like

```
<from>^/(?!whatever/)(.*),a([0-9]+)(,(.+))?.html(\?(.*))?$</from>
<to last="true">somepath.html?path=$2&amp;attributes=$4&amp;$6</to>
```

Its obvious I have change this part of the code:

```
(,(.+))
```

to have meaning of: match every string(examples: b3,c56,e12345) split by ',' until you meet specific string("stop") and then keep matching until you meet '.'

I tried using

```
(,(.+?(?=stop)))?
```

in

```
<from>^/(?!whatever/)(.*),a([0-9]+)(,(.?!(?=stop)))?,stop(,(.+))?.html(\?(.*))?$</from>
```

without successful result, as 'stop' is still getting matched as a normal string and my rewroten url looks like this:

```
"somepath.html?path=54&attributes=a1,b2,c3,stop,d4,e5&"
```

I'd appreciate if somebody steered me into valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following expression in the `from` tag:

```
^[^,]+,(a[0-9]+),(.*?),stop,?(.*)$
```

Note that it is a very generic expression. There are no fancy matches/groups above. If any of the matched groups are optional, use `?` to make them so.

Now, in the rewritten URL:

```
somepath.html?path=$1&attributes=$2&splitters=$3
```